# Can Bluetooth Low Energy Beacons act as receivers?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, nrf51822

I am working on a project which involves sending data from many [BLE beacons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy_beacon) to many other BLE beacons. To be more specific, I have two groups of beacons:

The first group consists of senders (or advertisers) which regularly (i.e. 500ms interval) only send (or advertise) their IDs, for example UUIDs, using a protocol like iBeacon. These beacons may be attached to moving objects.

The second group of beacons consists of receivers that receive the broadcasted IDs sent by sender beacons which are in their proximity (and then send this data over wifi to a central system; but this is another topic and not my concern now). These beacons are stationary and may be mounted on walls.

I know the first group (sender beacons) can do their job properly. The second group (receiver beacons) is my concern. I am not sure whether the beacons based on Nordic NRF51xxx or NRF52xxx chips can also act as receivers? If it is possible, any pointers or links to documentation/tutorials on how this can be done would be really appreciated.

P.S. (If it is possible,)  I was wondering whether beacons based on other chips like BLE chips produced by TI (e.g. CC2540) can also act as receivers?

P.P.S. Is it possible to connect wifi modules to beacons based on Nordic NRF51xxx or NRF52xxx chips?

Comment: can you simply not call your second group of bluetooth devices "beacons"? They do nothing that sounds like a beacon. Have you ever seen a real-world beacon (like, a lighthouse)? It doesn't receive.

Comment: You think that **you** can determine how those BLE transceivers  behave, only receiving etc. Well **you can't** because then they would not follow the Bluetooth protocol anymore. Bluetooth and BLE **rely** on two-way communication. Bluetooth is a point-to-point protocol and you cannot change that. The BT/BLE standard defines the functions that are available, **not you**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie that's true, but advertisements (as has become pretty popular as what is rightfully called BT *beacons*) are one-way, obviously.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sure, the **data** can travel one way but that does not necessarily mean that the **connection** is one way. I'm not so familiar with BLE and the beacon mode. All I know it that basic Bluetooth requires a two-way connection for setting up the connection, to agree on the frequency hopping scheme for example. Maybe that's different for these beacons. Have to educate myself here (worked on BT long ago before BLE was invented).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes. I have worked with BLE beacons in the context of advertising and have developed a very basic android app which fetch a dynamic content from the cloud based on the UUIDs advertised by the beacons in the proximity of the device (i.e. phone). But I am no way an expert on this. The reason I called the second group 'beacons' is that I have seen some people on the internet talk about write characteristics in android which allows you to send data to beacons, if I am not mistaken. I wanted to know by (for example) modifying the firmware of beacons can they act as receivers?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Let me clarify it: Yes, I know I can buy a raspberry pi board and connect a Bluetooth dongle to it and program it such that it can act as a beacon scanner (receives the broadcasted data by the beacons in the proximity). But I want to know whether the chips in the beacons can be programmed such that they act as beacon scanner? Thanks.

Comment: please STOP abusing words. A scanner is yet something different. You're asking whether these chips can be used as receivers for Bluetooth announcements. Not more, not less. No scanning. No beaconing.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yep, as far as I remember, it's really unsolicited advertisements, so no "connection". it's been a while for me, too.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ha ha ha! *Abusing words*! Please! Just search for 'Beacon scanner app' and you will find out what I mean! I asked exactly the same question with the same wording elsewhere and they readily replied with an answer without being excessively (so called) technical and puting too much emphasis on wording. By the way, just for your information: Yes, it is possible! Beacons based on the NRF5xxxx chips can act as receivers as well as sender. Thanks.

Comment: I don't farking care about whether how non-technical people abuse words, especially when naming apps. They're, for all I care, totally irrelevant. This is an engineering website, and we try to communicate as precisely possible. If you find this website not willing to bend to your wording as easily as you'd like it, I recommend you go where they do – I tried to help you improve your question, but it's absolutely up to you to take that up or not. Have a nice day!

Comment: Oh and since you said that you've gotten an answer elsewhere, it would be fair to answer your own question here, so that others on this site don't spend time giving you an answer you already have. Because that would be totally bad style of you not to do.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for correcting me. But I mean you could have done it much better than that and being helpful and constructive, like the person who has already answered my question. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to be helpful and constructive, sorry if that didn't work out.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think the confusion here stems from how we look at the BT system. The scanning/receiver usage case what OP means is (I guess) at the application level. So the BT chip could still (at the hardware level) receive (RX) and (sometimes) send (TX) but at an application level, it **only receives** data. As a hardware designer myself, I see receiving as a hardware function. App developers only see the application profiles and there could be a "receive only" profile (for advertising) I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect wifi modules to beacons based on Nordic NRF51xxx or NRF52xxx chips?

Depends highly on the module you selected. I've seen beacon modules that have none of the GPIOs easy accessible. But there are roughly similar priced breakout modules, which would allow easy access to UART,TWI and SPI peripherials.

> I am not sure whether the beacons based on Nordic NRF51xxx or NRF52xxx chips can also act as receivers?

They can have both roles in theory, but that requires a significant amout of RAM. Thus you most likely wanted to use NRF52 based modules with larger RAM and flash memory.

Note that you could try to use the mesh SDK for NRF52 instead of WLAN for communication between the fixed nodes.

> If it is possible, any pointers or links to documentation/tutorials on how this can be done would be really appreciated.

Nordicsemi has its own [infocenter](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp). Their SDKs ship with a bunch of examples.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot! I will definitely take a look at the mesh SDK.